# How do I handle an Integral bounds with pi?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So besides the pi throwing me off, the exponent is too.

Define the Integral:
$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}\ x^5 cos(x^6) dx $

My Attempt:

$u = x^6, dx=6x^5 , du=\frac{1}{6}sin(u^6)$

$=\frac{1}{6}sin(x^{6})  + C$

$= [(\frac{1}{6}sin((\sqrt[6]{\pi})^{6}) - (\frac{1}{6}sin((0)^{6}) ]$

I'm confused about this problem any guidance would be appreciated, I'm getting a decimal value but it is incorrect.

Comment: what's the problem? $\sqrt[6]{\pi}^6=\pi$

Comment: also $\sin 0=0$

Comment: qbert, thanks -- had a brain fart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your attempt 
$u = x^6, dx=6x^5 , du=\frac{1}{6}\sin(u^6)$

$=\frac{1}{6}\sin(x^{6}) \rvert_{[0,\pi]}$

$= [(\frac{1}{6}\sin((\sqrt[6]{\pi})^{6}) - (\frac{1}{6}\sin((0)^{6}) ]$
$=\frac{1}{6}\sin(\pi)-\frac{1}{6}\sin(0)=0-0=0$

Comment: Thanks Basanta!

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}} x^5 \sin (x^6)\ dx\\
u = x^6, du = 6 x^5 dx$

If you are doing "definite integration." I suggest you express your limits in terms of u.

$u(0) = 0\\
u(\sqrt [6]{\pi}) = \pi\\
\int_0^{\pi} \frac 16  \sin (u)\ du\\
- \frac 16  \cos (u)|_0^{\pi}
- \frac 16  (\cos \pi - \cos 0)\\
-\frac 16  (-2)\\
\frac 13\\
$

If you are doing indefinite integration.

$\int x^5 \sin (x^6)\ dx\\
u = x^6, du = 6 x^5 dx\\
\int \frac 16 \sin (u)\ du\\
-\frac 16 \cos (u) + C$

Now you would need to reverse the substitution

$-\frac 16 \cos (x^6) + C$

And you can do the indefinite integration technique and the apply the limits in terms of $x$ but it tends to both be more work and give more places to forget something stupid along the way.

$-\frac 16 \cos (x^6)|_0^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}\\
-\frac 16 (\cos (\pi) - \cos(0))\\
\frac 13$

As qbert has just brought to pointed out. The question is supposed to be
$\int_0^{\sqrt[6]{\pi}} x^5 \cos (x^6)\ dx$

And we perform the same u-substitution and transformation of the limits as above.

$\frac 16 \sin u|_0^{\pi}$

$\frac 16 (\sin \pi - \sin 0) = 0$

Which is somehow less satisfying.

Comment: the integrand has $\cos$, not $\sin$

Comment: I was just noticing that.